# PowerShell - why is my recursive function stopping near the 282th iteration?

Tags: excel, powershell, recursion

I've written a recursive function in PowerShell. The goal of this function is to create a set of folders (taken from an excel file) in a share points Online website using `Resolve-PnPFolder`.

I really don't understand why my function always stops near the 282th iteration.

I tried to debug but didn't find any result.

These are the function specifications:

- Read the excel file and all the values are collected from it
- For one line it builds a string that corresponds to the `-SiteRelativePath`
- At the end of the line it creates the file using `Resolve-PnpFolder` and call the function  again for the next line.

I've also discovered that it is not `Resolve-PnPFolder` that is causing the problem. So I commented it out.

Here's the code:

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  ## Create and excel object
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile) ## Import the excel file to workbook variable
$WorkSheetFolders = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item(1)

function Get-NewPath {
    param (
        [String] $old_path,
        [String] $new_path
    )

    return "$($old_path)/$($new_path)";
}
```

```
function Create-FoldersTemp {
    param (
        [String] $current_path,
        [int] $i, 
        [int] $j, 
        $excel_sheet_Cells
    )
    # Condition : Check if we are not a the end (row side)
    if ($NULL -ne ($excel_sheet_Cells.Item($i,2).value2)){
        ## Arrive to the end 
        # Create the folders with the current path and recall with i++ the function (recursive)
        if ($NULL -eq ($foldername = $excel_sheet_Cells.Item($i,$j).value2)){
            #Resolve-PnPFolder -SiteRelativePath $current_path
            write-host -f Blue "[$($i)] : $($current_path)"
            Create-FoldersTemp -current_path "" -i (++$i) -j 2 -excel_sheet $excel_sheet_Cells
        }
        else{
            Create-FoldersTemp -current_path (Get-NewPath -old_path $current_path -new_path $foldername) -i $i -j (++$j) -excel_sheet $excel_sheet_Cells
        }
    }
}
```

```
function Create-Folders {
    param (
        [int] $i, 
        [int] $j, 
        $excel_sheet_Cells,
        $URL
    )
    #Connect-PnPOnline -Url $URL -Interactive
    Create-FoldersTemp -current-path "" -i $i -j $j -excel_sheet_Cells $excel_sheet_Cells
}
```

```
Create-Folders -i 2 -j 2 -excel_sheet_Cells $WorkSheetFolder.Cells
Stop-Process -name Excel
```

Hope you can help me find what is causing this

Comment: 282 sounds arbitrary enough to be a data thing. Maybe print last line processed?

Comment: i'll try try to print it. By the way I am using Visual studio code

Comment: @JustAskingQuestions Is there a particular reason you use recursion for this? Why not a simple loop?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen trying to optimise the speed of my script

Comment: Tried to print outsite the (if we arrive at the last line)
But I didn't print
More over I don't think that it exit the function

Comment: Recursion != speed. You need to allocate extra stack memory every time you recurse, variable lookups become slower as scope depth increases etc.

Comment: I was talking about time complexity @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: That makes 2 of us. You don't think memory allocation takes _time_? :-)

Comment: I think that in this case using  recursion isn't effective. I'll try and use iteration

Comment: Thank you for your help, you helped me understand recursion :)

Comment: I'm definetly overloading my memory... I guess